# Get DayOFYear in XXX format in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to  get the day of the  year in XXX format. Like on 55th day it should show 055 and on 110th day it should just show 110.
(Get-Date).DayOfYear gives just  55, but the string format that I need to work with has to have a format of XXX

Comment: `(Get-Date).DayOfYear.ToString("000")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try This:
"{0:D3}" -f (Get-Date).DayofYear

[more info here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692795.aspx)